# How can I use elements in xxx.rb in xxx.css.scss?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the ".rb" file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def bg
  @images  = ["bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg", "bg4.jpg", "bg5.jpg","bg6.jpg","bg7.jpg","bg8.jpg"]
  @random_no = rand(8)
  @random_image = @images[@random_no]
end

end
```

This is the "css.scss" file:

```
#welcome
{
  background-image:url();
}
```

I want the `background-image` to display `@random_image`, but I have no idea what should be in `url()`.

Thanks!

Comment: in this case, really not easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't dynamically change the background via .css because it loads once, but you can make a small hack specifying styling in layout file. Check out similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944107/accessing-rails-controller-instance-variables-in-css).